# Running sum of an ArrayList with 2 possible operations

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a program insert two possible operations (* and +) in between inputed numbers and keep track of the total. The program simply reads from left to right so therefor do not apply BEDMAS

For instance if I inputed: 1 2 3

The output would be 1 + 2 + 3 -> Sum = 6

Or output would be  1 + 2 * 3 -> Sum = 9

Or output would be  1 * 2 + 3 -> Sum = 5
 Etc

I am having difficulty because my program continues to try to `numbers.remove()` from an empty ArrayList(numbers).

```
public static void calculate(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int target){
    ArrayList<Integer> temp_array = new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers);
    int sum = 0;
    int n = (numbers.size() - 1);
    System.out.println("This is where we calcutale L");

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {  
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        while (bin.length() < n)
             bin = "0" + bin;
        char[] chars = bin.toCharArray();
        char[] charArray = new char[n];

        while(charArrayCount < Math.pow(2,n)){
            for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
                charArray[j] = chars[j] == '0' ? '+' : '*';
            }
            for(char c : charArray){
                int current = numbers.get(0);
                if (c == '+'){
                  sum = sum + current;
                }
                numbers.remove(0);
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
            numbers = temp_array;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually 1 + 2 * 3 -> must be Sum = 7 if you respect the precedence order of the operators

Comment: your code is very hard to understand. I suggest instead of shorting your code, try to verbose it in order to understand your logic better.